# No cap after a period in Dragon Dictate 4

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

In [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm), when I say "Hello world period this is a test period", it outputs:

> Hello world. this is a test."

There is no cap after the first period. Is there any way to fix it?

This issue affects most programs: Evernote, the default Mac OS X mail application, Safari, Latexian, etc. There is no such issue using Dragon's notepad or Google Chrome.

Obviously I don't want to have to say "Cap" after each period.

Answer (score 1):

Considering it's not happening in every application (it works in the built-in Notepad and Google Chrome), I would think it's a bug. Have you reported this behavior to Dragon?